# How to match line & error in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

How can I match this error in the build with regex to locate line and file with `result_line_regex` & `result_file_regex`?

```
project4.dpr(9) Hint: H2164 Variable 'I' is declared but never used in 'Project3'
```

I have tried this but it won't work.

```
    "result_file_regex": "^.*\\(.*)/.?(.*)$",
    "result_line_regex": "^([^\\]*)\.(\w+)$",
```

Comment: `result_line_regex` and `result_file_regex` are the settings in the result view, not the entries you write into the build system. I think you could add something like `"file_regex": "^([\w\.]+)\((\d+)\)"`. The first group is the file name the second group is the line number. (It could be problematic, that it is just the file name and not the path to the file.)

Comment: That regex will not work in ST3. Red color over \

Comment: Did you try actually running the build system?

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments, `file_regex` is the setting that gets passed to `result_line_regex` (have a look at the `run()` method signature of `class ExecCommand` in `Packages/Default/exec.py`).

A good regex in your case would be `^([\w-]+\.\w+)\((\d+)\)`. The first group captures something like `my-file.ext` and the second one the digit(s) in parentheses.

In order to set that expression in a string in the `json` file you need to escape each backslash with another backslash (`\` is the escape character in strings), so it becomes:

```
"file_regex": "^([\\w-]+\\.\\w+)\\((\\d+)\\)"
```

Notice that the matched file has to be in the path of the file that is active when triggering the build system. If you want it to be relative to a certain path no matter where you trigger the build, you can also pass a working directory like:

```
"working_dir": "/path/to/my/source"
```

This will be set as `result_base_dir` in the output view.